# Woocommerce confirm booking email to show customer information

Tags: php, wordpress, function, email, woocommerce

I'm sure this is something very simple to do, but I just can't figure it out.

My questions concerns the WooCommerce booking confirmation email that is being sent to the admin. I would like it to contain all of the customer information including address and meta.

Does anyone know how to pull the info into the email?

Answer (score 0):

Read this, you will find the answer : https://www.sellwithwp.com/customizing-woocommerce-order-emails/

Comment: i've looked through many, and it's just not loading, including this link.